# org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException in Android 10

Tags: android, kotlin, mockito, uitest

I'm using mockito-core:3.1.0 with android 10 and have this code in my test

```
val testView: ViewGroup = mock()
whenever(testView.getChildAt(any())).thenReturn(topParentView)

val mockActivity = mock(Activity::class.java, RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS)
whenever(mockActivity.window.decorView.findViewById<View>(any())).thenReturn(testView)
doReturn(inputBitmap).whenever(screenShotUtil).takeScreenShot(any<View>())
```

It works fine in android 9 or lower but in android 10 the test fails with the following exception:

```
Misplaced or misused argument matcher detected here:

-> at com.econocheck.banking.ui.util.overlay.ScreenShotUtilTest.testTakeScreenshot(ScreenShotUtilTest.kt:156)

You cannot use argument matchers outside of verification or stubbing.
Examples of correct usage of argument matchers:
when(mock.get(anyInt())).thenReturn(null);
doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(mock).someVoidMethod(anyObject());
verify(mock).someMethod(contains("foo"))

This message may appear after an NullPointerException if the last matcher is returning an object
like any() but the stubbed method signature expect a primitive argument, in this case,
use primitive alternatives.
when(mock.get(any())); // bad use, will raise NPE
when(mock.get(anyInt())); // correct usage use

Also, this error might show up because you use argument matchers with methods that cannot be mocked.
Following methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified: final/private/equals()/hashCode().
Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.
```

pointing to:

```
whenever(mockActivity.window.decorView.findViewById<View>(any())).thenReturn(testView)
```

Comment: The message is explicitly saying the solution. Did you try to replace `any()` with `anyInt()` in that line?

Comment: Yeah, i tried with anyInt() but still the same error

Comment: Did you enable `final` mocking for mockito as described [here](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html)? `View#findViewById` is a `final` method.

Comment: yes, it has final mocking enabled as explained in the provided link